# Is there a guide for web.config settings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration

Hi is there a guide or tutorial or some kind of reference to learn how to work with asp/net mvc web.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [MSDN - ASP.NET Configuration Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx)
- [MSDN - ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)
- [MSDN - ASP.NET Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a reference of the "system settings", start with this page in MSDN: [ASP.NET Configuration File Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zeshe0eb.aspx)

If you're looking for information about how to add your own settings to the web.config file and read them from the application, then look at the [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)